# TSQL: Howto add a char to a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, row-number

I have the following statement

```
SELECT id, descr from mytable
```

which returns

1, 'Test1'
4, 'Test4'
6, 'Test6'
8, 'Test8'
22, 'Test22'

Now I want the display to Add a sequential character to the first 4 results...

'A', 1, 'Test1'
'B', 4, 'Test4'
'C', 6, 'Test6'
'D', 8, 'Test8'
'',22, 'Test22'

Thoughts?

Edit: Would prefer a SQL Server 2000 example if possible.

Comment: How about in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROWNUMBER < 4
           THEN CHAR(65 + ROWNUMBER - 1)
           ELSE ''
       AS <WHATEVER>
       ,X.id
       ,X.descr
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <WHATEVER>) AS ROWNUMBER
        ,id
        ,descr
    FROM mytable
) AS X
```

This in SQL Server 2005 and up.

In SQL Server 2000 (assuming id is your sort order and unique):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rownumbers.rownumber < 4
           THEN CHAR(65 + rownumbers.rownumber - 1)
           ELSE ''
       AS <WHATEVER>
       ,mytable.id
       ,mytable.descr
FROM (
    SELECT l.id, COUNT(*) AS rownumber
    FROM mytable AS l
    LEFT JOIN mytable AS r
        ON l.id >= r.id
    GROUP BY l.id
) AS rownumbers
INNER JOIN mytable
    ON mytable.id = rownumbers.id
```

Comment: How about in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: There's a few ways to skin this in SQL Server 2000 - the triangle join method is the one I chose here.

Comment: This looks like it is going to work, but id is unique but not the sort order. What I get for using a contrived example I guess. :)

Comment: Thank you. Between this answer and Ted's I got it to work beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single select statement in SQL Server 2000.  SQL Server 2000 has no ROWNUM statement.

If you want to use a temp table you could do it with the IDENTITY function.

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) rownum, 
       id, 
       descr 
INTO #mytable 
from mytable

SELECT CASE WHEN ROWNUMBER < 4
       THEN CHAR(65 + ROWNUMBER - 1)
       ELSE ''
   AS <WHATEVER>
   ,X.id
   ,X.descr
FROM #mytable X
ORDER BY rownum
```

NOTE: IDENTITY function can only be used in a SELECT INTO statement.

Comment: I guess you can do it in one statement, looks like Cade's SQL 2000 solution might work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using a solution that was 75% Cade's and 25% yours.